# How do I allow non-authenticated users to access content in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a site in cakephp 2.x where I want that a guest user (not logged in) can see same pages:
users/login
users/forgot_password
users/reset_password

I have AuthComponent that can't access my page. I can access to users/login but not to forgot_password and reset_password, if i try to ccess always redirect to the login page.

This is my AppController with AuthComponent:

```
public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginAction' => array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'login', 'admin'=>false),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'login'),
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller'=>'projects', 'action'=>'index'),
            'authError' => 'Questa risorsa non sembra appartenere al tuo account, oppure non hai eseguito l\'accesso',
            'autoRedirect' => false,
            'authorize' => array(
                'Controller',
                'Actions' => array(
                    'actionPath' => 'controllers'
                )
            ),
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

In this case I can't access to forgot_password and reset_password.

But if I change it to this:

```
public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginAction' => null,
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'login'),
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller'=>'projects', 'action'=>'index'),
            'authError' => 'Questa risorsa non sembra appartenere al tuo account, oppure non hai eseguito l\'accesso',
            'autoRedirect' => false,
            'authorize' => array(
                'Controller',
                'Actions' => array(
                    'actionPath' => 'controllers'
                )
            ),
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

I have set `null` to `loginAction` in this case I can access to forgot_password and reset_password but page are blank without errors, body are empty. These page are simply html without query like this:

controller action

```
public function forgot_password(){

}
```

view

```
<div>
    <p>RESTORE PASSWORD</p>
</div>
```

Someone can help me? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `beforeFilter()` callback, add `$this->Auth->allow('forgot_password');`

Api: [AuthComponent:allow()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-AuthComponent.html#_allow)